# Schengen visa and Indian passport stolen in India

Tags: visas, schengen, passports, india, lost-documents

Last night someone stole my bag in Delhi. My bag contained laptop and a passport with an unused schengen visa. I have my trip planned for Germany and the flight leaves in 6 days. Issuing a new passport is not an option because it takes upto a month to issue a new passport.

Is there any way I can still travel to Germany? Can the Germany embassy help me in this case?

Comment: If you lost your India passport, then no you can not leave India and go to Europe.  You need to reschedule, replace your passport, request a re-issue of the visa, then go.

Comment: And, after reporting your passport stolen to the authorities in Indian (police and passport office), you should let the German Consulate/Embassy know, so that the attached visa can be invalidated. Worse case would be for someone else to use both to enter Germany.

Comment: Yes, what @Dorothy mentions would be very bad. Report this to both German and Indian authorities ASAP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm sorry to say there is nothing you can do to catch it up in six days.

To add to what other honorable commenters say, normally in India you can try to apply for [Tatkaal passport](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqTatkaalPassports). This is an emergency passport which is issued very quickly - if you are lucky, you can get one in a 1-2 days. Unfortunately it is not available in your case, as Tatkaal is not available when your passport was stolen: see [case II (D) on Page 10](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/pdf/ApplicationformInstructionBooklet-V3.0.pdf)

And without a passport you can't leave India at all.